# How to get the number of columns of a csv file?

Tags: matlab

I have a huge csv file that I want to load with matlab. However, I'm only interested in specific columns that I know the name.

As a first step, I would like to just check how many columns the csv file has. How can I do that with matlab?

Comment: count the number of commas till a newline then add one maybe?

Comment: The problem is that there is no newline in my case, so fgetl does not work :(

Comment: CSV's have a delimeter for columns, and a newline for rows.  How is yours set up?

Comment: If there is no newline, what is the seperator between records?

Comment: What if the lines in the CSV file have a variable number of fields? There are plenty of related questions here on SO for reading all sorts of CSV files...

Answer (score 2):

As Jonesy and erelender suggest, I would think this will do it:

```
    fid=fopen(filename);
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    fclose(fid);
    length(find(tline==','))+1
```

Since you don't seem to know what kind of carriage return character (or character encoding?) is being used then I would suggest progressively sampling your file until you encounter a recognizable CR character. One way to do this is to loop over something like

```
    A = fscanf(fileID, ['%' num2str(N) 'c'], sizeA);
```

where `N` is the number of characters to read. At each iteration test `A` for presence of carriage return characters, stop if one is encountered. Once you know where the carriage return is just repeat with the right N and perform the `length(find...)` operation, or alternately accumulate the number of commas at each iteration. You may want to check that your file is being read along rows (is it always?), check a few samples to make sure it is.

Answer (score 0):

1-) Read the first line of file
2-) Count the number of commas, or seperator characters if it is not comma
3-) Add 1 to the count and the result is the number of columns in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If the csv has only numeric value you can use:

```
 M=csvread('file_name.csv');

 [row,col]=size(M);
```